# How Can I Load the Questions for different subject in 'listview' OnClick List Item

Tags: android, listview

How Can I Load the Questions for  different subject in `listview` item's click. For e.g; if Android is clicked it should load Android MCQ in another Activity

[image]

Comment: use Webservices to load questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            T item = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            switch (item) { //or if, else

                // logic here
            }
        }
    });
```